# Serilog - AppSettings MinLevel not working

Tags: serilog

I am trying to wire up my sinks and it seems for my rolling file sink my debug messages are not being logged (only info and above). Is my configuration wrong?

```xml
<!-- Serilog Configuration -->
<add key="serilog:using:Email" value="Serilog.Sinks.Email" />

<!-- Configure Serilog Email Sink -->
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.mailServer" value="***" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.toEmail" value="***" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.fromEmail" value="***" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.mailSubject" value="Comply360 Portal Endpoint (DEV)" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Warning" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{CorrelationId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />

<!-- Configure Serilog RollingFile Sink -->
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Debug" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\comply360-portal-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{CorrelationId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with your `RollingFile` sink config per se - it will only log messages with log level `Debug` or above (i.e. it will not log `Verbose` messages) as you intended.

However, the minimum log level for Serilog in general is `Information`, so it doesn't even send to your sink.

You need to change Serilog's default minimum level to at least `Debug`, in your case:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
```

Your final config should look like this:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Debug" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\log-portal-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{CorrelationId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
```

---

Of course, if you later decide to add any sink that logs `Verbose` messages and above, you'll need to change the minimum-level to `Verbose` too.

i.e. `serilog:minimum-level` should always be the lowest level from all of your sinks.

Comment: really, you can't set the min level at the sink level?

Comment: and actually that is why i posted my code. it is not logging at the debug or higher level. it is logging at the info or higher (default)

Comment: i see what you are saying now. however, my rolling file did indeed still log messages but adding the global min level did the trick for all my sinks.

Comment: according to https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings 
and confirmed by my testing, you also need 

<add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />

This is confirmed here:  Solved for Github user dstj : https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/454#issuecomment-243561807

I edited the answer accordingly, and hope it will be approved.

Comment: “ serilog:minimum-level should always be the lowest level from all of your sinks.”.   From https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings#adding-minimum-level-overrides: “ Since Serilog 2.1, minimum level overrides can be added to change the minimum level for some specific namespaces. This is done with the setting key serilog:minimum-level:override: followed by the source context prefix.”