# Different Minimum Level Logs Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there a way to differentiate what level is logged between the different loggers for Serilog? I want to be able to log MinimumLevel Debug to the console output but only Warning and above to my file output. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and this is what the appsetting.json currently looks like:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "IsJson": true,
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\Logs\\Log-{Hour}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Is it something like another parameter under "Args"? I've tried "minimumnLevel" in this location but it did not work.

Comment: How is this done in app.config?

Comment: For a .Net application? I haven't needed this level of detail/differentiating for .net, just .net core. This is all I added to the .Net config after adding serilog: <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\log-{Hour}.txt" />

Comment: I was able to get this to work in the app.config. The trick is to make sure serilog is actually paying attention with this line.   <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
Then for the logging to the file I used <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Debug" /> and then use this to log to the console <add key="serilog:write-to:Console.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Information" /> Sorry for the formatting, I'm not sure how to do line feed in the comment.

Comment: Thank you @PHenry for fishing out the app/web config setting to set the minimum level to debugging. I kept trying things like `serilog:MinimumLevel:Debug` to no avail

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is `restrictedToMinimumLevel`. This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/19) shows some examples of this, but for your example, you just need to add `restrictedToMinimumLevel` to your `Args` for `RollingFile`:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "IsJson": true,
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\Logs\\Log-{Hour}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 11):

Working from the answers above, this is how I set it up in code as opposed to config

```
LoggerConfiguration GetConfig()
                => new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.Seq(serverUrl: "http://localhost:5341", restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
                    .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error);
            var logger = GetConfig().CreateLogger();
            builder.RegisterInstance(logger).As<ILogger>();
```

After I did this, it worked for log level Information and above. Debug didn't work. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379152/494635) explained why.

I had to set a 'global' minimum level like this.

```
LoggerConfiguration GetConfig()
            => new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Seq(serverUrl: "http://localhost:5341", restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose();
```

Answer (score 8):

In your configuration you have one Serilog logger, but you have 2 *sink*s. One of your sinks is RollingFile and the other is Console.

[You can override (but only raise) the minimum logging level per sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#overriding-per-sink), The argument is called `restrictedToMinimumLevel`.

Since you want to raise the minimum logging level from your logger's default `Debug` to `Warning` in your file sink, in your appsettings.json file, it would look like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "IsJson": true,
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\Logs\\Log-{Hour}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  },
```