# How to use Serilog to log all log messages in one request to single entry

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog

Want to check if it is possible to log all messages in one request as single entry.

I was looking at this https://andrewlock.net/using-serilog-aspnetcore-in-asp-net-core-3-reducing-log-verbosity/ but not I am after.

For instance, I have a .Net Core web app with

```
public MyController(IService myService, ILogger<MyController> logger)
        {
            _myService = myService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myService));
            _logger = logger;
        }

[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery( Name = "Id")] List<string> ids)
        {          
            _myService.DoSomething();
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"Some controller logs here");
            return new OkObjectResult();
        }
```

And for IService:

```
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

public DoSomething()
{
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"Some service logs here");
}
```

Is Serilog able to log "Some controller logs here" & "Some service logs here" under one entry? instead of two entries?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can add middleware on your app. It will capture incoming and outgoing top requests.

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //First, get the incoming request
        var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);

        //Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        //Create a new memory stream...
        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //...and use that for the temporary response body
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            //Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
            await _next(context);

            //Format the response from the server
            var response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);

            //TODO: Save log to chosen datastore

            //Copy the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream, which is then returned to the client.
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var body = request.Body;

        //This line allows us to set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
        request.EnableBuffering();

        //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        //...Then we copy the entire request stream into the new buffer.
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //We convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        //..and finally, assign the read body back to the request body, which is allowed because of EnableRewind()
        request.Body = body;

        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
    {
        //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //...and copy it into a string
        string text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client can read it.
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Return the string for the response, including the status code (e.g. 200, 404, 401, etc.)
        return $"{response.StatusCode}: {text}";
    }
}
```

And do not forget inject on your startup file the middleware.

```
app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
```

You may configure your serilog file like this:

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": "Error",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "\\log-{Date}.log",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  },
]
```

},

It will write to the file at the selected destination.

And please note, here are minimum level of serilog.
[Different Minimum Level Logs Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046747/different-minimum-level-logs-serilog)

Maybe it will be help you.