# Serilog not logging information to SQL Server but logs errors only

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an asp.net core 6.0 project, I have implemented logging using Serilog. I have configured it to insert records in SQL Server table, but it logs only errors and fatal errors. I need to log information as well, please suggest if I need to change my code to log all types of logs supported by Serilog.

**C# Code: -**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {                
            ConfigureLogging();
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            Log.Information("App starting");
            host.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Fatal(exception, "Error starting - Main method");
        }
    }
   
   private static void ConfigureLogging()private static void ConfigureLogging()
    {
        try
        {               
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                //.MinimumLevel.Warning()
                //.Filter.ByExcluding((le) => le.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
                .CreateLogger();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Fatal(exception, "Error starting - ConfigureLogging method");
        }
        finally
        {
            //Log.CloseAndFlush(); //no need to close bcz we are using it as a singleton instance.
        }
    }
    
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(Log.Logger);
   }
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHangfireJobs hangfireJobs, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, DBContext dbContext, Serilog.ILogger logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
   {
   }
```

**appSettings.json**

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        //"Microsoft": "Warning",  // auto write MS warnings
        //"System": "Warning"      // auto write System warnings
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
       {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=tcp:xyz.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=abc;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sql;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
          "tableName": "APILogs",
          "schemaName": "dbo",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
            "customColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "APIPath",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 150
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ControllerName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "MethodName",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 80
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "LineNumber",
                "DataType": "int"
              }
            ]
          },
          "timeStamp": {
            "columnName": "TimeStamp",
            "convertToUtc": true
          },
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithThreadId"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different Minimum Level Logs Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046747/different-minimum-level-logs-serilog)

Comment: I have already tried setting MinimumLevel, but didn't work for me.

Comment: What did you set it to?  Seems you want at least `Information`

Comment: For SQL Sink you set `"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"`, though.

Comment: ^^ and `"Default": "Warning"` ... how can you expect to get information-level messages? Set both to "`Information`".

Comment: thanks @Fildor, issue fixed, MinimumLevel was set at 2 places, Default and restrictedToMinimumLevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppSettings.json, please change

```
"MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
```

TO

```
"MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
```

Then it will start logging Information and below (Information, Warning,Error, Critical)

Comment: thanks @Anshul, I was setting only Default property but the restrictedToMinimumLevel property is also needs to be changed.